# What is the standard way of accessing X11 color mappings in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, colors, x11

Googling around, I see [this list](http://xona.com/colorlist/RGBcolorlist.txt), which provides a useful name to rgb mapping.

Of course, I can easily copy this file, store it somewhere, and read it, but I was wondering, is there a standard way of accessing this list from C/C++ from some standard location (hopefully, without a lot of hassle)?

Even a standard location in a *nix system would be useful, since reading/parsing the file is trivial.

Fwiw, I am running gcc 4.7.3 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names) (not a great reference I know)

X11root/lib/X11/rgb.txt

which is likely:

/usr/lib/X11/rgb.txt

Comment: +1 this is useful - now, I just need to track down X11root conventions

Answer (score 0):

Googling around some more, it looks like the standard location may be:

```
/etc/X11/rgb.txt
```

For checking out the colors, the `xcolors` program is useful.

Install with `sudo apt-get install xcolors`

Comment: Have you checked the `xcolors` source to see what it does?

Comment: @muistooshort - lol, is it hard-coded, I wonder: http://www.codeforge.com/read/180711/xcolors.c__html
perhaps it generates the file!

Comment: I do not have that file in my distro, therefore it is not a standard location.

Comment: @BЈовић +1 thanks for the warning - I will continue searching

Comment: You could poke around in the Xt resource converters, I know they handle various color formats (including the names) but, alas, I haven't done any Xt or Xm work in a couple decades so I'm a bit foggy.

Comment: @muistooshort - hehe, good idea, but that was what I was hoping to avoid - I see hacky solutions out there like this in perl (just go over a list of possible locations): http://www.derose.net/steve/utilities/SHELLUTILS/xcolors